# Error when trying to upload a file with drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

We are getting the following error:

> Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError File not found: 1l6lKqzMgq7IsoyKg-pZoaFqWrTGRAG8i. [404] Errors  Message[File not found: 1l6lKqzMgq7IsoyKg-pZoaFqWrTGRAG8i.] Location[fileId - parameter] Reason[notFound] Domain[global]"}

The error points that the location (parent) of the item does not exists but the ID was generated by the drive API.
What could be the reason ?

Update:

Code:

```
   body.Parents = new List<string>() { item.Location };
                using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(item.FilePath,
                                                System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                                                System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress IU;
                        fileRequest = driveService.Files.Create(body, 
     stream, GetMimeType(item.FilePath));
                        //fileRequest.ChunkSize = 256 * 1024 * 20;

                        //fileRequest.ResponseReceived += 
     Request_ResponseReceived;
                        //fileRequest.ProgressChanged += 
     Request_ProgressChanged;
                        fileRequest.UploadSessionData += 
     Request_UploadSessionData;

                        item.ResumeRetriesCount = 0;
                        ProgressPercent = 0;
                        FileSize = new FileInfo(item.FilePath).Length;

                        Uri uploadUri = GetSessionRestartUri();

                        if (uploadUri == null)
                        {   
                            fileRequest.ProgressChanged += (o) =>
                            {
                            }
                        }.....
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: That the id you are using is incorrect its hard to know when we cant see your code.

Comment: The ID is def correct. I receive it back from the API once created. I also call the drive.Files.List()  for this ID and it's there. Could there be something to do with the format of the ID? btw, sometimes it works thought. it used to work all the time, now stated to be unstable.

Comment: show me what you have in body

Comment: body.Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.FilePath);
                    body.Description = "";
                    body.MimeType = GetMimeType(item.FilePath);
                    
      // set the location of the file , parent folder ID.
                    body.Parents = new List<string>() { item.Location }; 
The strange thing is that it sometime works sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Another "strange" thing:
I've created a folder via my code, and then selected a huge number of files to upload (2000+ images). all went through up to 1070 or so and then started to receive the same exception of file not found (referring to the parent ID)
Could there be a limit of files that can be uploaded to a folder?

Comment: It sounds more like its file not found with your resumable upload to me.   This isnt the directory not found error.

Comment: But the error points at the parent directory ID that cannot be found.